# $n\bar k=\overline{nk}$ in $Z_m$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, congruence-relations

I was reading *Algebra* of Hungerford, the (sketch of) proof of Theorem 3.6.

*Definitions* : Let $m$ be a positive integer.
The equivalence relation '$\equiv$' modulo $m$ partitions $\mathbb Z$ into $m$ equivalence classes $\bar a$ for $a=0,1,2,\cdots,m-1$.
The set $\mathbb Z_m$ of all such equivalence classes is a group under addition, defined by $\bar a+\bar b=\overline{a+b}$.
Note that $\bar a=\bar b$ in $\mathbb Z_m$ iff $a\equiv b$ (mod $m$).

Then, is the following true for every integer $n$ and $k$?
$$n\bar k=\overline{nk}\quad(\text{in }\mathbb Z_m)$$

my answer : *yes*

examples : In $\mathbb Z_6$,
$$3\bar5=\bar5+\bar5+\bar5=\overline{15}$$
$$0\bar5=\bar0$$
$$(-2)\bar5=-(\bar5+\bar5)=-\overline{10}=\overline{-10}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes:

$n\bar k=\underbrace{\bar k+\cdots+\bar k}_{\text{n-times}}=\overline {\underbrace{k+\cdots+k}_{\text{n-times}}}=\overline{nk}$, since $\overline{a+b}=\bar a+\bar b$ by definition.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!