# $m\bar a = \bar m \cdot \bar a$ in the ring $\mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $n\geq 1$ be an integer and consider the quotient ring $\mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z$. Let $\bar a$ be one of its element (i.e., an equivalence class).

Consider $m\in \mathbb Z$ and remember that $m\bar a$ is the notation for repeated addition of $\bar a$: if $m\geq 1$, $m\bar a = \bar a+\ldots+\bar a$.

I want an "abstract algebra" argument for the equality $$m\bar a = \bar m \cdot \bar a.$$

I have a pedestrian proof: induction on $m$ proves the equality for all $m\geq 0$, and for $m\leq 0$ we have $$m\bar a = -((-m)\bar a) = -(\overline{- m} \cdot \bar a) =\bar m \cdot \bar a.$$

I'm looking for a shorter proof, possibly using some adequate morphism.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3483636/n-bar-k-overlinenk-in-z-m?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Because $\mathbb{Z}$ is a commutative ring one has that quotients by all ideals form rings, i.e. $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is a ring where the ring strucutre is inherited from $\mathbb{Z}$. Let me specify:

Let $A$ be any commutative ring with a unity element $1$. Let $\mathfrak{a}\subset A$ be an ideal. Then $A/\mathfrak{a}$ is a ring with the following operations:

- $(a+\mathfrak{a})+(b+\mathfrak{a}) = (a+b) + \mathfrak{a}, \ \forall a,b\in A$
- $(a+\mathfrak{a})\cdot (b+\mathfrak{a}) = (ab) + \mathfrak{a}, \ \forall a,b\in A$

and one cheks *once* that these operations are well defined etc. but these are simple tasks. Furthermore one gets a canonical ring homomorphism $\phi:A\to A/\mathfrak{a}, x\mapsto x+\mathfrak{a}$ (that this indeed is a ring homomorphism is easily checked) and it holds that $\ker \phi = \mathfrak{a}$.

Back to the concrete example we thus get a canonical ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}, x \mapsto x+n\mathbb{Z}$.
Now clearly every ring is an algebra over $\mathbb{Z}$ (there is a canonical ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ into any commutative ring with $1$). Therefore we get an induced homomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules where we define the $\mathbb{Z}$-module strucutre of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ as $(m\cdot (k+n\mathbb{Z})):= mk + n\mathbb{Z}$ (this again is the module structure given by the fact that $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is an algebra over $\mathbb{Z}$).

Hence we get $m\cdot(k+\mathbb{Z}) = mk+n\mathbb{Z}$. As desired.

The point I am trying to make is that the formula you are trying to prove has nothing to do in particular with the ring $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, rather it holds for any 'ol commutative ring by the fact that we get canonical morphisms from $\mathbb{Z}$ into any ring (this can be rephrased in the language of category theory: $\mathbb{Z}$ is an inital object in the category of commutative unitary rings).

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $R$ be a commutative ring.

Define the multiple of a ring element $r\in R$ inductively as follows:

$0\cdot r = 0$, $(m+1) \cdot r = m\cdot r +r$ for $m\geq 0$ and $m\cdot r = (-m)\cdot (-r)$ for $m<0$.

Then for each $m>0$, $m\cdot r = r+\ldots+r$, the $m$-fold of $r$, and for each $m<0$, $m\cdot r = (-r)+\ldots+(-r)$, $-m>0$ times $-r$.

Example: $2\cdot r = r+r$ and $(-2)\cdot r = (-r)+(-r)$.

Now the **left-hand side** of your equation has the rigorous definition $m\cdot \bar a$ given as the $m$-fold of $\bar a$.

In view of the **right-hand side**, $\bar m = \bar 1+\ldots +\bar 1$, the $m$-fold of $\bar 1$, if $m>0$, $\bar m= \bar 0$ if $m=0$, and $\bar m =-\bar 1 +\ldots + (-\bar 1)$ if $m<0$.

Example: $\bar 2\cdot \bar a = (\bar 1 + \bar 1)\cdot \bar a$ and $\overline{-2}\cdot \bar a = ((-\bar 1) + (-\bar 1))\cdot \bar a$.

To extend the example to your equation:
$2\cdot \bar a= \bar a + \bar a$ and $\bar 2\cdot \bar a= (\bar 1 + \bar 1)\cdot \bar a = \bar a + \bar a$.